# Hooking into Hibernate's query generation

Tags: hibernate, hook, hql

I would like to implement *virtual views* with a preprocessor. A simple example:

HQL before:

```
FROM PublishedArticle a
```

Effective HQL after:

```
FROM Article a
WHERE a.published = true
```

Essentially I need a way to process queries before they get executed (instead of creating views on-the-fly which would have a high cost).

Comment: HQL is parsed at deployment

Comment: Can't you create a `PublishedArticle` view in your DBMS directly? What DBMS are you using?

Comment: @sp00m These dynamic views could be user dependent. At least that's the plan.

Comment: @vbence What is meant by user-dependant? A `PublishedArticle` view in your DBMS would simply lists any `Article` where `a.published = true` for example.

Comment: @sp00m Imagine an example with the `WHERE a.owner='3'` clause. `3` being the ID of the current user. Or a more difficult `WHERE` clause, when creating a view for every permutation is impossible. - That's why I called them `virtual views`.

Comment: this is just a dynamic query isn't it ? Use the criteria api, or build up a sql string.

Comment: @NimChimpsky The query is not necessarily dynamic, at least I'm looking for a way to pre-process HQLs. - A way to hook into the process.

Comment: From what I know, Hibernate uses ANTLR to convert HQL to SQL and I haven't seen ANTLR expose any hooks or events to customise the tree generation process.  I therefore doubt that Hibernate would provide any hooks either.  I would say that creating custom, dynamic queries would be the only way.  In my current application we allow users to create fully dynamic queries.  We use QueryDSL with Hibernate JPA to construct the queries based on user inputs as we have no upfront knowledge of which fields will be chosen, what joins will be applied or even which tables will be involved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How I can configure StatementInspector in Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39112308/how-i-can-configure-statementinspector-in-hibernate)

Comment: @AlexR How could it be? Finding that question implies that you know that there is such a thing as `StatementInspector` - that you just mentioned 5 years after the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `StatementInspector` to completely rewrite the SQL to suit your needs.

For further reading: [How I can configure StatementInspector in Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39112308/how-i-can-configure-statementinspector-in-hibernate)

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you do that with a Hibernate *filter*? Of course for things more complex than `WHERE` it wouldn't work:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/filters.html